# program cannot find libQt3Support.so.4 even though I have it in ~/lib

Tags: linux, qt4, shared-libraries

I installed Qt4 in my local home in a Ubuntu system and the Qt4 libraries are in ~/lib. I have another program (hawkeye for genome assembly) dependent on Qt4 however when I run that it gives the error message:

error while loading share libraries: libQt3Support.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I checked ~/lib and all the Qt libs are there. Do I need to add the path ~/lib to anywhere?

Comment: try executing: `ldconfig` and trying again

Comment: Did you check for 32/64bit mismatch?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to debug problems like this is to take a look at the `ldd` output. For example:

```
$ ldd yourProg
linux-gate.so.1 => (0xffffe000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb7e3d000)
libQtGui.so => /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4.7.0 (0xb7f7f000)
libQt3Support.so => (not found)
...
```

The above output will tell you if it's picking up your copy of Qt or the system version.  Then you can set LD_LIBRARY_PATH or edit ld.so.conf and rerun `ldconfig`. For example:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/qt
$ ldd yourProg
```

Or (as root):

```
# echo "/path/to/your/qt" >> /etc/ld.so.conf
# ldconfig
$ ldd yourProg
```